# unable to add Firebse to my android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to add firebase to my app and followed every step as told in https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
but as soon as a launch the app it crashes with the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.examplefirestore, PID: 29977
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #8 bootstrap method
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have also cross checked my gradle moudle and every thing seems to be fine, here is my gradle module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.examplefirestore"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'

}
```

Even in graple project everything seems to be ok to me i have cross checked this multiple times, this is my gradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are missing

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

in your **build.gradle (app)**.

Comment: i m using not kotlin but java...i guess you are talking for kotlin? because in the firebase i didn't find such thing.. please correct me if i m wrong

Comment: I'm not sure about Kotlin since I'm not much familiar with it; however, this is for Java (as well). It also says "JavaVersion" if that helps you understand.

Comment: Have you checked the following: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: hey bro that actually worked...THANK YOU. I don't know why its not written in the link I mentioned

Comment: ...and put this in the android {} tag.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It's so weird this isn't mentioned in the installation docs :|